# -std=c++11 flag unrecognized in gcc/g++ 4.4.6

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, c++11, g++

I have some code written using the C++11 standards, and our g++ version is 4.4.6, so as far as I can tell, C++11 should be supported (from 4.3 onwards).

However upon trying to compile with the flags `-std=c++11 -std=gnu++11`, I get repetitions of the errors

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option `-std=c++11`
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option `-std=gnu++11`
```

Compiling with `-std=c++0x` produces errors such as

```
DeviceInfo.cpp:22: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
```

corresponding to this line of code:

```
for (cl::Platform& plat : platforms)
```

Is this a C++11 specific bit of Syntax? (it doesn't look like it to me, but all this code has been given as an example so should work as provided with the compiler.)

Any help?

Comment: You'll need GCC >= 4.7 to get the `c++11` flag. 4.4 is too old, you won't get the range-based for either AFAIK, even with `-std=c++0x`. Please _at least_ read the man page for the compiler, the options it supports are listed  in there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`-std=c++11` setting is supported by much later versions of GCC. The initial support for nascent C++11 was enabled by `-std=c++0x` setting. This is probably what you should try.

And yes, the `for` syntax you are trying to use is chiefly C++11 syntax.

Comment: Cheers for the quick help :)

Comment: I'd appreciate if a source link is also shared.

Answer (score 3):

It appears as if range-based for loops are supported in 4.6 and newer.

[This page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) shows GCC support for C++11 features.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (cl::Platform& plat : platforms)
```

Yes, it is C++11 specific usage. GCC 4.7 or later supports C++11 with `-std=c++11` option meanwhile.